# How many Alternative/VR Missions are there in MGS2?

Tags: achievements, metal-gear-solid-2-sons-of-liberty, metal-gear-solid-hd-collection

I'm considering going for the "Virtually Impossible" achievement, but it would nice to know how much I need to do. If your answer broke down the number of missions per character and/sub-group that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are **511**.

I made the following spreadsheet, which might be of interest to somebody who wants to track their progress:
http://www.thunderpeel2001.com/GameFAQs/MGS2-Missions.xlsx

Top tip: These are some **amazing** tutorial videos by user "Dat Boi Treezy" for getting past the tougher levels, too: http://bit.ly/VirtuallyImpossible

Here's the complete list I put together:

**RAIDEN**
*VR MISSIONS*
Sneaking - Sneaking x 10
Sneaking - Eliminate All x 10
Weapon Mode x 40
First Person View Mode x 5
Variety Mode x 7
*ALTERNATIVE MISSIONS*
Bomb Disposal Mode x 5
Elimination Mode x 10
Hold-up Mode x 10
Photograph Mode x 6

Raiden Total = 103

**RAIDEN (Ninja)**  (available when Raiden is 50% or higher)
*VR MISSIONS*
Sneaking - Sneaking x 10
Sneaking - Eliminate All x 10
Weapon Mode x 5
Variety Mode x 1
*ALTERNATIVE MISSIONS*
Bomb Disposal Mode x 5
Elimination Mode x 10

Raiden (Ninja) Total = 41

**X RAIDEN**    (available when Raiden and Raiden (Ninja) are both 100%)
*VR MISSIONS*
Streaking Mode x 1

X Raiden Total = 1

**SNAKE**
*VR MISSIONS*
Sneaking - Sneaking x 10
Sneaking - Eliminate All x 10
Weapon Mode x 40
First Person View Mode x 5
Variety Mode x 7
*ALTERNATIVE MISSIONS*
Bomb Disposal Mode x 5
Elimination Mode x 10
Hold-up Mode x 10
Photograph Mode x 7

Snake Total = 104

**PLISKIN**  (available when Snake is 50% or higher)
*VR MISSIONS*
Sneaking - Sneaking x 10
Sneaking - Eliminate All x 10
Weapon Mode x 40
Variety Mode x 2
*ALTERNATIVE MISSIONS*
Bomb Disposal Mode x 5
Elimination Mode x 10
Hold-up Mode x 10

Pliskin Total = 87

**SNAKE (Tuxedo)**  (available when Snake and Pliskin are both 100%)
*VR MISSIONS*
Sneaking - Sneaking x 10
Sneaking - Eliminate All x 10
Weapon Mode x 40
Variety Mode x 2
*ALTERNATIVE MISSIONS*
Bomb Disposal Mode x 5
Elimination Mode x 10
Hold-up Mode x 10

Snake (Tuxedo) Total = 85

**SNAKE (MGS1)**  (available when Snake (Tuxedo) is 100%)
*VR MISSIONS*
Sneaking - Sneaking x 10
Sneaking - Eliminate All x 10
Weapon Mode x 40
Variety Mode x 3
*ALTERNATIVE MISSIONS*
Bomb Disposal Mode x 5
Elimination Mode x 10
Hold-up Mode x 10

Snake (MGS1) Total = 88

Total VR Missions = 358
Total Alternative Missions = 153

**Total Missions = 511**

Comment: Top tip: Also, the final levels start to become extremely difficult. This guy put together an amazing list of tutorials that help tremendously if you need it: http://bit.ly/VirtuallyImpossible